# Can't build cordova phonegap project android

Tags: java, android, cordova, compiler-errors, phonegap-cli

I'm new to building apps in cordova/phonegap.
Now today I tried to build my app for android but it failed to compile.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.
It runs fine on browser and the phonegap app on my mobile phone.

**Phonegap version 0.4.3 / Cordova android 5.2.2 (java jdk1.8.0_101)**

**I'm using this plugins in my project:**

- cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
- cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1 "File"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"

Nothing special I think?

The compile error I get:

- What went wrong:

```
Execution Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note:  (my_project_folder)\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I want to add, dummy projects compile fine (hello world projects from phonegap)
Really have no clue what it could be?
Where do I have to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by updating de android SDK lib. After installing API 25, the compiling/build succeeded.